# How to call PUT router from POST router in Node.js Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In Node/express I have a `POST` request that if it contains an `id` I would like it to call the `PUT` method instead. No redirect, just how to call the put method from the post method?

```
router.put('/:id', function(req, res) {
  // code ...
});

router.post('/:id?', function(req, res) {
  if (req.params.id) {
    // call PUT method
  }
});
```

I don't want to do a redirect, just make it as if it was part of the current request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the code to a named function and call that instead.

```
function handlePut(req, res) {
  // code ...
}

router.put('/:id', handlePut);

router.post('/:id?', function(req, res) {
  if (req.params.id) {
    return handlePut(req, res);
  }

  // don't forget to handle me!
});
```

Comment: Nice answer. But wouldn't the request not even go through that handler if there isn't an id? Seems like that `if(req.params.id)` is redundant.

Comment: The id is optional in POST. That's what the ? is for.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize you could do that with the `?`. Thanks